# height of xap object works fine in IE7 but not working in IE8

Tags: asp.net, html, css, silverlight-4.0

I am hosting the silverlight xap object in aspx page. The aspx page contains two `<div>`.
In the first `<div>` i am having the html menu and in the second `<div>` i am having the xap. I gave `height=95%;` for xap object. It works fine with IE7 but in IE8 the height of the xap object is only around 30%. What may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. The height has to be set in pixels. Also to set the height dynamically, use screen.availHeight and set it in javascript code.